# Trying to remove duplicates for individual columns in a range of columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to remove duplicates for an individual column in a range of columns in my worksheet.  So far I have gotten this.

```
Sub removeDups()
Dim col As Range
For Each col In Range("A:Z").Columns
    With col
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    End With
Next col
End Sub
```

This continues to give me a 1004 error, and I am guessing its the structure of my

```
.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:xYes
```

line, but I haven't been able to figure that part out.

Comment: The code works for me, but your code differs to what you are saying is the line that crashes (i.e. `.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:xYes` which has `Header:xYes` instead of the `Header:=xlYes` in the code)

Answer (score 1):

As per [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) says, you have to pass an array in `Columns` parameter to `RemoveDuplicates` method.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,2), Header:=xlYes
```

or use defined range:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A100").RemoveDuplicates
```

Note: using `Range("A:Z")` without context may provide unexpected results, depending on what sheet is currently active.

Comment: The `Columns` parameter doesn't **have** to be an array - `Columns:=1` is fine and is what the macro recorder will generate

Comment: @YowE3K, well, i qouted MSDN documentation. This is exactly what has been wrote: `Columns - Array of indexes of the columns that contain the duplicate information. If nothing is passed then it assumes all columns contain duplicate information.`

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft's documentation and Microsoft's implementation are not always consistent.

Comment: @YowE3K, yeah. It's quite possible. I've seen few incompatibilities. This is probably the one of them.